# Certificate Based Authentication Using Camel Jetty

Tags: ssl, apache-camel, jetty, mutual-authentication

I have a issue where i have to pass client certificate for the Authentication purpose.

My code:

```
   <camel:sslContextParameters id="sslContextParameters">

     <camel:keyManagers keyPassword="indigo">
        <camel:keyStore resource="/home/sahil/Demo/new.jks" password="changeit"/>
    </camel:keyManagers>

    <camel:trustManagers>
     <camel:keyStore resource="/home/sahil/Demo/123.jks" password="changeit"/>
       </camel:trustManagers>
        <camel:serverParameters clientAuthentication="WANT" />    
</camel:sslContextParameters> <to uri="jetty:https://xx.x.xx/activate"/>
```

Every time i hit this service i get a error

> 2017/09/01 15:32:38 [info] 3934#3934: *11 client sent no required SSL certificate while reading client request headers,

And when i hit the URl with curl command and pass the client certificate it is showing success

Answer (score 1):

The reference to your contextParameter is missing in your jetti-uri.
It should look like:

`<to uri="jetty:https://xx.x.xx/activate?sslContextParametersRef=sslContextParameters"/>`

This is from the [Camel Wiki](http://camel.apache.org/jetty.html%20Camel%20Jetty):

**Spring DSL based configuration of endpoint**

`xml<camel:sslContextParameters id="sslContextParameters"><camel:keyManagers keyPassword="keyPassword"> <camel:keyStore resource="/users/home/server/keystore.jks" password="keystorePassword"/> </camel:keyManagers> </camel:sslContextParameters> <to uri="jetty:https://127.0.0.1/mail/?sslContextParametersRef=sslContextParameters"/>`

Comment: Thanks lahu89,   i have tried the same but still receiving the same error

Comment: Try to activate logging. I recommend the VM parameter -Djavax.net.debug=ALL.
It is many to read but you will see whether and which certificates will be used.
See also: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html